# How to anticipate in python if methods give outputs or change the object?

Tags: python, methods, output, variable-assignment

I'm trying to learn python and even though I now know the name of some methods, I still have to google their usage, since I never know if the method gives an output that I have to assign, or if it changes the input:

```
mylist = list()
givesnone = mylist.append("text")  # why no list output?
print(givesnone)

mylist[0].replace("text", "replaced")  # why not replacing?
print(mylist) # not replaced
mylist[0] = mylist[0].replace("text", "replaced")
print(mylist) # replaced
```

I want to be able to anticipate the behavior of methods without searching if I know their name, so how can I know if I have to assign the output or not?

Comment: You need to check whether the method works "in place". You could, as the answer suggests, use `help()` but it's one of those things where you are much better to remember the common examples. I don't want to give the impression that programmers remember all the different methods that they use (I google hundreds of times a day, as does everyone else I know) but this is one that you'll probably want to keep in memory

Comment: The fun comes when you have something like `pandas.DataFrame.append()` which doesn't work in place, while `list.append()` does. c'est la vie.

Comment: But is it actually not possible to guess if there is an output or not? Is it complete random or are there unwritten laws? I thought of something like for lists there is never an output, for strings there is always? ;)

Comment: The laws are written in the docs ;) or you have to memorize the one you use the most.
Unfortunately it is not always consistent. You can also use an IDE/editor (e.g. Spyder) with auto-completion which usually shows the function/method signature as you type it, so it is easier for you.

Comment: No, there are no laws for whether something should operate in place. I guess if you want to be able to "chain" methods then they should always return the object but you can't rely on any of this IMO. People design things in different ways

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [`help()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#help) method to view help information.

If you use an IDE to help you develop, for example, `PyCharm`. Then you can use the shortcut keys to jump to the method definition page, such as `command + b` on Mac.

Comment: These shortcuts are indeed very helpful! But still I'm interested if there is some system for methods having outputs or not?

Comment: @Nabla_ All I know is the `Debug` mode of `PyCharm`, which might let you see some output. Usually you can get a general idea of how to use it in the description information of the method.